# Exporting MVC3 Print view to PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

Is it possible with MVC3 (using 3rd party plugins if necessary) to generate a PDF dynamically using the print view of a page? As in, the layout you see if you print or print preview the view.

I know that iText(sharp) can create a PDF out of a normal view of a page but I need to create the print view PDF (via the controller preferably) so that it can be emailed.

I had Crystal Reports in place previously but have scrapped it in favor of HTML reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by implementing Rotativa (available from NuGet). It's much simpler and more effective than other converters around (gets a bit tricky with custom authentication though).